# Drupal batch process - how to redirect with StreamedResponse in finish callback

Tags: http, drupal, response, httpresponse, drupal-batch

I am making a batch to export many entities and then to download a result file. Here is a part of my finish callback:

```
    ....
    if ($success && !empty($results['file'])) {
      // Create a response to trigger the file download.
      $response = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($results) {
        readfile($results['file']);
        unlink($results['file']);
      });

      // Set response headers.
      $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
      $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="exported_values_' . time() . '.xlsx"');
      $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');

      // Send the response.
      $response->send();
      ....
```

The export file is downloaded successfully.

But, I want to redirect to a specific page afterwards, but not to stay on the batch process page.

I tried adding `header('Location: xxurlxx')` into the `StreamedResponse` function; then also outside with `$response->headers->set('Location', xxurlxx);` but the result is not good 'cause it redirects correctly But it no longer downloads the file.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

When you send the file from php, your are sending a response to the request. So the request is finished. You cannot do anything after.

One way would be to do it in Javascript but it's tricky
Another way would be changing your "download file" link to open the file in a new tab in addition to a javascript redirection on first page

Comment: Yes, finally i did it from javascript. I used the bar progress Kkkk. it isn't clean but it works Kkk.

Comment: I made observer on the bar progress precent Kkkk